# extrarowheight vs arraystretch

Tags: macros

What's the difference between these two in a table environment?

I've seen they cause somewhat the same result, but I have no idea what is the difference, except that `arraystretch` is used in a scale factor and `extrarowheight` seems to be added in length.

Comment: Great question. I note that Lamport mentions `\arraystretch` in his documentation, but not `\extrarowheight` (I've scribbled it into my book on the same page).  It might lead us to *believe* that they are functionally equivalent alternatives, but I'm sure David Carlisle will straighten us out :^)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's the difference between adding and multiplying.

`\arraystretch` is part of the LaTeX format it multiplies the height and depth of the "strut" used to space out table rows by the specified factor.

`\extrarowheight` is an extra parameter added by the `array` package which adds a specified length to the height of the strut used for padding table rows.

If you want to keep text away from horizontal lines without disturbing everything else too much `\extrarowheight` is usually better.

Comment: Isn't there a difference with multi-line table cells (`@p{...}`)? IIRC `\arraystretch` works like `\baselinestretch`, adding space between such lines.

Comment: @alexis the commands just have the effect that I said. `\arraystretch` only affects the strut added to the table row it does not affect the baseline of lines within a p column.