# Make less space between lines on a table

Tags: tables, line-breaking, line-spacing

I have a big table where I need to use multiple lines on each cell. The table is too big though so I need the space between lines on each cell to be smaller.

I found on another post that I could use this to make several lines on a cell

```
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
```

And this is part of my table

```
\begin {table}[H]
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}
      {| >{\footnotesize}C{2cm} | >{\footnotesize}C{2cm} | >{\footnotesize}C{2cm} | >{\footnotesize}C{2cm} | >{\footnotesize}C{2cm} |} \hline Imagen a comparar & $1^{er}$ resultado de clasificación & $2^{do}$ resultado de clasificación & $3^{er}$ resultado de clasificación & $4^{to}$ resultado de clasificación \\
      \hline \specialcell{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{barley/b2.jpeg} \\ barley2 \\(\textbf{Clase 1})} &
      \specialcell{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{barley/b2.jpeg} \\barley2 \\(0.0)} &
      \specialcell{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{barley/b4.jpeg} \\barley4 \\(0.236041)} &
      \specialcell{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{barley/b5.jpeg} \\barley5 \\(0.248987)} &
      \specialcell{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{barley/b1.png} \\barley1 \\(0.333787)} \\ 
      \hline \specialcell{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{canvas/c21.jpeg} \\canvas21 \\\textbf{Clase 2}} &
      \specialcell{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{canvas/c21.jpeg} \\canvas21 \\(0.0)} & 
      \specialcell{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{canvas/c28.jpeg} \\canvas28 \\(0.309975)} & 
      \specialcell{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{seeds/s9.jpeg} \\seeds9 \\(0.321354)} &
      \specialcell{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{canvas/c14.jpeg} \\canvas14 \\(0.338891)} \\ 
      \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Resultados de la clasificación ascendente de texturas Outex.} \label{cuadroOutex}
 \end{center}
\end{table}
```

So any idea how can I make the linebreaks smaller I tried adding [0.5ex] after each linebreak within a cell but the space didn't seem to change.

Comment: `\setlength\extrarowheight{-1pt}` might do it, changing `-1pt` to desired value.

Comment: You haven't given any information about your definitions so hard to say but it looks like your `C` columns are par columns already so would allow mult-line content so the `\specialcell` command is not needed. Also you probably want to use `\centering` rather than `\begin{center}` `\end{center}` as the latter adds vertical space.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Would you like to write an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As David Carlisle pointed out at [extrarowheight vs arraystretch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114421/extrarowheight-vs-arraystretch), `\extrarowheight` is a length added by the `array` package to change the default inter-line gap setting between array or tabular lines.  It can be positive or negative (though it appears the negative values are limited in how close they can scrunch the lines).

Here is a demonstration showing both negative and positive `\extrarowheight`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin {table}[ht]
\begin{center}
  \setlength\extrarowheight{-3pt}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
  1 & 2 & 3\\
  4 & 5 & 6\\
  7 & 8 & 9\\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{My caption}
 \end{center}
\end{table}

\begin {table}[ht]
\begin{center}
  \setlength\extrarowheight{6pt}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
  1 & 2 & 3\\
  4 & 5 & 6\\
  7 & 8 & 9\\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{My caption}
 \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Simply `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}` (Default value is 1).

It can be placed before `\begin{tabular}{ c c c }` or at beggining of document for all tables.

Source: [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/How_do_I_change_column_or_row_separation_in_LaTeX_tables%3F)

Follow a working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin {table}[ht]
\begin{center}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0} %%% Default value: 1, place  before \begin{tabular}{ c c c }.
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
  1 & 2 & 3\\
  4 & 5 & 6\\
  7 & 8 & 9\\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{My caption}
 \end{center}
\end{table}

\begin {table}[ht]
\begin{center}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8} %%% Default value: 1, place  before \begin{tabular}{ c c c }.
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
  1 & 2 & 3\\
  4 & 5 & 6\\
  7 & 8 & 9\\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{My caption}
 \end{center}
\end{table}

\begin {table}[ht]
\begin{center}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} %%% Default value: 1, place  before \begin{tabular}{ c c c }.
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
  1 & 2 & 3\\
  4 & 5 & 6\\
  7 & 8 & 9\\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{My caption}
 \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]