# Creating a two column table for a math class

Tags: two-column, columns

I am having trouble creating two column tables. I want to create 2 two column tables side by side, but my code doesn't seem to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\title{Example: Exponents}
\author{Ms. Lampianerani} 
\date{}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\maketitle



\begin{center}
 \setlength\extrarowheight{6pt}
 \begin{tabular}{ | l | p{4.5cm} |}
 \hline
  Expression & Equivalent Value Simplified\\ \hline
  $2^2 $&  4  \\ \hline
  $2^1$ &  2 \\ \hline
  $2^0$ &  1 \\ \hline
  $2^-1$ &   $\frac{1}{2}$  \\ \hline
  $2^-2$ &  $\frac{1}{4}$  \\  \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{center}

 \begin{center}
   \setlength\extrarowheight{6pt}
 \begin{tabular}{ |  l  | p{4.5 cm} |}
 \hline
 Expression & Equivalent Value Simplified\\ \hline
 $3^2$ &    \\ \hline
 $3^1 $ &   \\ \hline
 $3^0$ &  \\ \hline
 $3^{-1}$  &   \\ \hline
 $3^{-2} $ &   \\  \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{center}

 \end{document}
```

I want one table with the powers of 2 on the LHS side and another with the powers of 3 on the RHS side, but this code doesn't even work for the powers of 2.

EDIT: I now can create a table with powers of 2. I only need the code to create side-by-side columns with space in between.

Comment: You need math mode to use powers: `$2^2$`. Also for fractions: `$\frac{}{}$`.

Comment: Ok but how do I make it look better? The horizontal lines cut into the exponents and I need to know how to create one table on the LHS and another table on the RHS. Thanks for your input

Comment: You can use two consecutive `tabular` environments. Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126781/14757

Comment: thank you that code helped. i am working on side-by-side

Comment: please fix your example document to not have math mode errors, and to include your powers of 3 data. In what way do you want it to look different from a 4 column table? tabular are positioned like a letter, to put two side by side just put them next to each other in the source with possible space between.

Comment: You have a paragraph break between them so they are one above the other: just delete `\end{center} \begin{center} \setlength\extrarowheight{6pt}` so the tabular are printed on the same line

Comment: When I deleted those 3 lines I just get one on top of the other and not side by side. I've tried minipage and it still doesn't work.

Comment: yes because like putting two words side by side TeX will wrap the line if it is too long and your tables are wider than half the text width.

Comment: also, you can not go 2^-1 as that just superscripts the -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\title{Example: Exponents}
\author{Ms. Lampianerani} 
\date{}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\maketitle



\begin{center}\small
% \setlength\extrarowheight{6pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
  \begin{tabular}{ | l | p{3cm} |}
 \hline
  Expression & Equivalent Value Simplified\\ \hline
  $2^2 $&  4  \\ \hline
  $2^1$ &  2 \\ \hline
  $2^0$ &  1 \\ \hline
  $2^{-1}$ &   $\frac{1}{2}$  \\ \hline
  $2^{-2}$ &  $\frac{1}{4}$  \\  \hline
 \end{tabular}%
\hfill
 \begin{tabular}{ |  l  | >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm} |}
 \hline
 Expression & Equivalent Value Simplified\\ \hline
 $3^2$ &  9  \\ \hline
 $3^1 $ &  3 \\ \hline
 $3^0$ & 1 \\ \hline
 $3^{-1}$  &  $\frac{1}{3}$  \\ \hline
 $3^{-2} $ &   $\frac{1}{9}$ \\  \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{center}


or

\begin{center}\small
% \setlength\extrarowheight{6pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm} |c| l | >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm} |}
 \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}
  Expression & Equivalent Value Simplified&&
  Expression & Equivalent Value Simplified\\ \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}
  $2^2 $&  4 &&
  $3^2 $&  9  \\ \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}
  $2^1$ &  2 &&
  $3^1$ &  3 \\ \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}
  $2^0$ &  1 &&
  $3^0$ &  1 \\ \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}
  $2^{-1}$ &   $\frac{1}{2}$  &&
  $3^{-1}$ &   $\frac{1}{3}$  \\ \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}
  $2^{-2}$ &  $\frac{1}{4}$  &&
  $3^{-2}$ &  $\frac{1}{9}$  \\  \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}
 \end{tabular}
 \end{center}



 \end{document}
```

Comment: @karlkoeller oh no, I was hoping to get the site's first unsung hero badge:-) (I have one of those on Stack Overflow:-)

Comment: Make a little edit and I will unupvote :-)