# Increasing space in Latex table

Tags: tables

The following code generates a table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{M{20mm}M{20mm}M{20mm}}
& positive spin, $s > 0$ & negative spin, $s > 0$\\ \cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{Local integrals of motion} & \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }
{$P_{s} = \int_{C} [T_{s+1}(z)d\text{z}+\Theta_{s-1}(z)d\bar{\text{z}}]$} & 
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{$\bar{P}_{s} = \int_{C} [\bar{T}_{s+1}
(z)d\bar{\text{z}}+\bar{\Theta}_{s-1}(z)d\text{z}]$}      \\ [1ex] \cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{Local currents} & \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{$(T_{s+1}, 
\Theta_{s-1})$} & \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{$(\bar{\Theta}_{s-1}, 
\bar{T}_{s+1})$}     \\ \cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{Continuity equation} & \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }
{$\partial_{\bar{\text{z}}}T_{s+1}(z) = \partial_{\text{z}}\Theta_{s-1}(z)$} 
& \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{$\partial_{\text{z}}\bar{T}_{s+1}(z) = 
\partial_{\bar{\text{z}}}\bar{\Theta}_{s-1}(z)$} \\ \cline{1-3}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Local integrals of motion and local conserved currents of integrable quantum field theories}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This code generates the following table:

[image]

I would like to extend the vertical space in each row for aesthetic beauty. Cal you help with this?

Comment: Very well, but think of us, poor mortals, who have not the least idea of what is the `M` column type…

Comment: I don't know that either. I think it means middle. Please edit the code as you feel appropriate.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126781/14103.

Comment: Why not put a complete compilable code instead of guessing us?

Comment: Comment aside: needless to load `amsmath` if you load `mathtools`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd get rid of all vertical rules and of 3 of the 4 horizontal rules. I'd also use a `tabularx` environment. And, out of an abundance of caution, I'd write `\mathrm{z}` instead of `\text{z}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} % automatic math mode
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt} % default value: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} Y CC @{}}
& \text{positive spin}, s > 0 
& \text{negative spin}, s > 0\\ 
\midrule
Local integrals of motion
& P_{s} = \int_{C} [T_{s+1}(z)d\mathrm{z}
                +\Theta_{s-1}(z)d\bar{\mathrm{z}}] 
& \bar{P}_{s} = \int_{C} [\bar{T}_{s+1}(z)d\bar{\mathrm{z}} 
                +\bar{\Theta}_{s-1}(z)d\mathrm{z}] \\ 
Local currents 
& (T_{s+1}, \Theta_{s-1}) 
& (\bar{\Theta}_{s-1}, \bar{T}_{s+1}) \\ 
Continuity equation
& \partial_{\bar{\mathrm{z}}}T_{s+1}(z) = 
    \partial_{\mathrm{z}}\Theta_{s-1}(z)
& \partial_{\mathrm{z}}\bar{T}_{s+1}(z) = 
    \partial_{\bar{\mathrm{z}}}\bar{\Theta}_{s-1}(z) \\ 
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Local integrals of motion and local conserved currents of 
         integrable quantum field theories}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If the textblock is wide enough to make line breaks in the first column unnecessary (as would appear to be the case in the screenshot you posted), adding a bit of whitespace between the rows will be welcome:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs,array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}} % automatic display-math mode
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
% Let LaTeX figure out amount of intercolumn whitespace:
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} 
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l CC }
\toprule
& \text{positive spin}, s > 0 
& \text{negative spin}, s > 0\\ 
\midrule
Local integrals of motion
& P_{s} = \int_{C} [T_{s+1}(z)\,d\mathrm{z}
          +\Theta_{s-1}(z)\,d\bar{\mathrm{z}}] 
& \bar{P}_{s} = \int_{C} [\bar{T}_{s+1}(z)\,d\bar{\mathrm{z}} 
          +\bar{\Theta}_{s-1}(z)\,d\mathrm{z}] \\
\addlinespace 
Local currents 
& (T_{s+1}, \Theta_{s-1}) 
& (\bar{\Theta}_{s-1}, \bar{T}_{s+1})     \\ 
\addlinespace
Continuity equation
& \partial_{\bar{\mathrm{z}}}T_{s+1}(z) = 
       \partial_{\mathrm{z}}\Theta_{s-1}(z)
& \partial_{\mathrm{z}}\bar{T}_{s+1}(z) = 
      \partial_{\bar{\mathrm{z}}}\bar{\Theta}_{s-1}(z) \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Local integrals of motion and local conserved 
         currents of integrable quantum field theories}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Some `\addlinespace`s between rows would improve the table, in my opinion.

Comment: @Bernard - Thanks. I've posted an addendum, in which I use extra whitespace between the rows if the text block is wide enough to make line breaks in the first column unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

I can propose this, with some improvements. All these `\multicolumn`s are not necessary. I added some padding at thetop and bottom of cells with the `cellspace` package, borrowed  the `\widebar` command from `mathabx`(to be used above capital letters) and increased the size of the integrals to a medium size with the `\medint`command from `nccmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{array, makecell, cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8> mathx7
<8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9
<10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|Sl|*{2}{>{$}Sc<{$}|}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}& \multicolumn{1}{Sc}{positive spin, $s > 0$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{negative spin, $s > 0$}\\ %
\hline
\makecell[l]{Local integrals\\ of motion} & P_{s} =\medint \int_{C}\bigl[T_{s+1}(z)\,\mathrm d{z}+\Theta_{s-1}(z)\,\mathrm d\bar{{z}}\bigr] &
\widebar{P}_{s} = \medint\int_{C}\bigl [\widebar{T}_{s+1} (z)\,\mathrm d\bar{z}+\widebar{\Theta}_{s-1}(z)\,\mathrm d z\bigr] \\ [1ex] %
\hline
Local currents & (T_{s+1}, \Theta_{s-1}) & (\widebar{\Theta}_{s-1}, \widebar{T}_{s+1}) \\ %
\cline{1-3}
Continuity equation & \partial_{\bar{z}}T_{s+1}(z) = \partial_{z}\Theta_{s-1}(z)
& \partial_{z}\widebar{T}_{s+1}(z) =\partial_{\bar{z}}\widebar{\Theta}_{s-1}(z) \\%
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Local integrals of motion and local conserved currents of integrable quantum field theories}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]