# Table doesnt match the size of the page

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have a long table in Word so I have used a website to convert this table so it can be put in LaTeX. I want my table to be displayed like this:

[image: wanted result]

However, in LaTeX it ended up looking like this:

[image]

Here's the code for the table above. I want it to match the page size without going out of bounds and I want it to look like Word version. Can anyone help me with it please?

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Fonctionnalités &
  ID &
  User story &
  Priorité \\ \hline
 &
  1.1 &
  En tant qu’administrateur je dois m’authentifier à la page admin pour y   accéder &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4} 
 &
  1.2 &
  En tant qu’employé RH je dois m’authentifier à la page RH et y accéder &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4} 
 &
  1.3 &
  En tant que client je dois m’authentifier à la partie pro pour y   accéder &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4} 
 &
  1.4 &
  En tant que webmaster je dois m’authentifier à la page de gestion de   contenu pour y accéder &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4} 
\multirow{-5}{*}{Authentification} &
  1.5 &
  En tant que client je peux réinitialiser mon mot de passe &
  moyenne \\ \hline
 &
  2.1 &
  En tant qu’administrateur je peux ajouter/ modifier/supprimer des   comptes des utilisateurs (Employé RH, client) &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4} 
 &
  2.2 &
  En tant qu’administrateur je peux consulter les détails d’un compte &
  faible \\ \cline{2-4} 
 &
  2.3 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}En tant que client je dois envoyer une demande d’inscription qui va être   vérifiée par l’administrateur &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4} 
\multirow{-4}{*}{Gestion   des comptes} &
  2.4 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}En tant qu’administrateur je peux vérifier les demandes d’inscription &
  élevée \\ \hline
 &
  3.1 &
  En tant que webmaster je peux ajouter/modifier/supprimer des nouveautés,   produits ou solutions &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4} 
 &
  3.2 &
  En tant qu’utilisateur je peux consulter les nouveautés, produits et   solutions &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4} 
\multirow{-3}{*}{Gestion du   contenu} &
  3.3 &
  En tant que client je souhaite recevoir des notifications à propos les   nouveautés &
  faible \\ \hline
 &
  4.1 &
  En tant que employé RH je peux ajouter/modifier/supprimer des offres   d’emploi ou de stages &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4} 
 &
  4.2 &
  En tant que employé RH je peux consulter les candidatures &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4} 
 &
  4.3 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}En tant qu’utilisateur je peux consulter les offres d’emploi/stage &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4} 
\multirow{-4}{*}{Gestion   des offres de stage et d’emploi} &
  4.4 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}En tant qu’utilisateur je peux postuler pour un offre d’emploi/stage &
  élevée \\ \hline
 &
  5.1 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}En tant que client je peux remplir un ticket de support &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4} 
 &
  5.2 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}En tant que service client je peux consulter les tickets de support &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4} 
\multirow{-3}{*}{Gestion   des tickets de support} &
  5.3 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}En tant que client je peux envoyer une demande de service &
  élevée \\ \hline
 &
  6.1 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}En tant que webmaster je dois sélectionner des clients pour partager   des documents &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4} 
 &
  6.2 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}En tant que client je peux consulter les documents partagés &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4} 
\multirow{-3}{*}{Gestion   des documents} &
  6.3 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}En tant que client je veux être notifié lors de la réception d’un   document &
  faible \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  First, don't use `\resizebox`; shrinking the text that way makes it hard to read.  The cells with a lot of text are best treated as paragraphs; see [How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12703) for some suggestions.  To add some extra "clearance" around lines, see [extrarowheight vs arraystretch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114421).

Comment: Does the Word version of the table span two separate pages? Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

- you should provide an MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which can be compiled as it is
- don't scale table, this only make inconsistent almost unreadable font size
- to solve your problem, you should enable longer text in cells to be divided into several lines (as is done in your Word table)
- for this you only need to define new column specification, where for the first two column select column type with determined widths
- for table instead of `tabular` rather use

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{<column specifications>}`
```

or

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{<column specifications>}`
```

or use `tblr˛table as defined by` tabularray` package (see addendum)

- it is not clear what you like to obtain with inserting `\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}` (white color) in some cells
- a possible solution by use of the `tabularx` package  is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}% for left aligning text in cells

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|p{10em}|l|L|l|} % <--- changed
% table body is the same as in your table
\hline
Fonctionnalités &
  ID &
  User story &
  Priorité \\ \hline
 &
  1.1 &
  En tant qu’administrateur je dois m’authentifier à la page admin pour y   accéder &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4}
 &
  1.2 &
  En tant qu’employé RH je dois m’authentifier à la page RH et y accéder &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4}
 &
  1.3 &
  En tant que client je dois m’authentifier à la partie pro pour y   accéder &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4}
 &
  1.4 &
  En tant que webmaster je dois m’authentifier à la page de gestion de   contenu pour y accéder &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4}
\multirow{-5}{=}{Authentification} &
  1.5 &
  En tant que client je peux réinitialiser mon mot de passe &
  moyenne \\ \hline
 &
  2.1 &
  En tant qu’administrateur je peux ajouter/ modifier/supprimer des   comptes des utilisateurs (Employé RH, client) &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4}
 &
  2.2 &
  En tant qu’administrateur je peux consulter les détails d’un compte &
  faible \\ \cline{2-4}
 &
  2.3 &
   En tant que client je dois envoyer une demande d’inscription qui va être   vérifiée par l’administrateur &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4}
\multirow{-4}{=}{Gestion   des comptes} &
  2.4 &
   En tant qu’administrateur je peux vérifier les demandes d’inscription &
  élevée \\ \hline
 &
  3.1 &
  En tant que webmaster je peux ajouter/modifier/supprimer des nouveautés,   produits ou solutions &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4}
 &
  3.2 &
  En tant qu’utilisateur je peux consulter les nouveautés, produits et   solutions &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4}
\multirow{-3}{=}{Gestion du   contenu} &
  3.3 &
  En tant que client je souhaite recevoir des notifications à propos les   nouveautés &
  faible \\ \hline
 &
  4.1 &
  En tant que employé RH je peux ajouter/modifier/supprimer des offres   d’emploi ou de stages &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4}
 &
  4.2 &
  En tant que employé RH je peux consulter les candidatures &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4}
 &
  4.3 &
  En tant qu’utilisateur je peux consulter les offres d’emploi/stage &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4}
\multirow{-4}{=}{Gestion   des offres de stage et d’emploi} &
  4.4 &
  En tant qu’utilisateur je peux postuler pour un offre d’emploi/stage &
  élevée \\ \hline
 &
  5.1 &
  En tant que client je peux remplir un ticket de support &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4}
 &
  5.2 &
  En tant que service client je peux consulter les tickets de support &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4}
\multirow{-3}{=}{Gestion   des tickets de support} &
  5.3 &
  En tant que client je peux envoyer une demande de service &
  élevée \\ \hline
 &
  6.1 &
  En tant que webmaster je dois sélectionner des clients pour partager   des documents &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4}
 &
  6.2 &
  En tant que client je peux consulter les documents partagés &
  élevée \\ \cline{2-4}
\multirow{-3}{=}{Gestion   des documents} &
  6.3 &
  En tant que client je veux être notifié lors de la réception d’un   document &
  faible \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}%
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**

- another possible solution is use `tblr` table
- in this case is advisable to remove all `\hline`s from table body (what is simple to do with help of your editor)
- with it is table code is much shorter, clear and with niccer vertical spacing of cells' contnets, but this is paid with a bit longer duration of the compilation
- this time is to table added possible coloring of selected cells (for this is defined new /no white/ color and short command to coloring cells)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycolor}{HTML}{eefaea}% FFFFFF ?, real color is unknown

\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewTableCommand\SCC{\SetCell{bg=mycolor}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htp]
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {X[0.33, l] c X[j] l}
             }
Fonctionnalités 
    & ID    & User story & Priorité \\
\SetCell[r=5]{l}    Authentification 
    & 1.1   & En tant qu’administrateur je dois m’authentifier à la page admin pour y   accéder 
                & élevée            \\
    & 1.2   & En tant qu’employé RH je dois m’authentifier à la page RH et y accéder 
                & élevée            \\
    & 1.3   & En tant que client je dois m’authentifier à la partie pro pour y   accéder 
                & élevée            \\
    & 1.4   & En tant que webmaster je dois m’authentifier à la page de gestion de contenu pour y accéder 
                & élevée            \\
    & 1.5   & En tant que client je peux réinitialiser mon mot de passe 
                & moyenne           \\
%
\SetCell[r=4]{l}   Gestion   des comptes
    & 2.1   & En tant qu’administrateur je peux ajouter/ modifier/supprimer des   comptes des utilisateurs (Employé RH, client) 
                & élevée            \\
    & 2.2   & En tant qu’administrateur je peux consulter les détails d’un compte 
                & faible            \\
    & 2.3   & \SCC  En tant que client je dois envoyer une demande d’inscription qui va être   vérifiée par l’administrateur
                & élevée            \\    
    & 2.4   & \SCC  En tant qu’administrateur je peux vérifier les demandes d’inscription
                & élevée            \\
%
\SetCell[r=3]{l}    Gestion du   contenu
    & 3.1   & En tant que webmaster je peux ajouter/modifier/supprimer des nouveautés,   produits ou solutions
                & élevée            \\
    & 3.2   & En tant qu’utilisateur je peux consulter les nouveautés, produits et   solutions 
                & élevée            \\
    & 3.3   & En tant que client je souhaite recevoir des notifications à propos les   nouveautés 
                & faible            \\
%
\SetCell[r=4]{l}    Gestion   des offres de stage et d’emploi
    & 4.1   & En tant que employé RH je peux ajouter/modifier/supprimer des offres   d’emploi ou de stages 
                & élevée            \\
    & 4.2   & En tant que employé RH je peux consulter les candidatures 
                & élevée            \\    
    & 4.3   & \SCC  En tant qu’utilisateur je peux consulter les offres d’emploi/stage
                & élevée            \\
    & 4.4   & \SCC  En tant qu’utilisateur je peux postuler pour un offre d’emploi/stage
                & élevée            \\
%
\SetCell[r=3]{l}    Gestion   des tickets de support
    & 5.1   & \SCC  En tant que client je peux remplir un ticket de support
                & élevée            \\
    & 5.2   & \SCC  En tant que service client je peux consulter les tickets de support
                & élevée            \\
    & 5.3   & \SCC  En tant que client je peux envoyer une demande de service
                & élevée            \\
%
\SetCell[r=3]{l}        Gestion   des documents
    & 6.1   & \SCC  En tant que webmaster je dois sélectionner des clients pour partager   des documents
                & élevée            \\
    & 6.2   & \SCC  En tant que client je peux consulter les documents partagés
                & élevée            \\
    & 6.3   & \SCC  En tant que client je veux être notifié lors de la réception d’un   document
                & faible            \\
\end{tblr}%
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text block borders)

Comment: Also, this answer has (correctly) removed the resizebox.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever else you do, don't use `\resizebox` to shoe-horn the table into the width of the textblock.

What else to do?

- Allow automatic line breaking to occur in columns 1 and 3
- Unless the document's margins are quite narrow or an unsually font size is in use, the full table is unlikely to fit on a single page. I suggest you replace the table/tabular combination with a single [xltabular](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xltabular) environment. This will allow automatic page breaking to occur, if and where needed. The `xltabular` package combines the machineries of the `longtable` and `tabularx` packages.

> I want [the LaTeX table] to look like the Word version

- An obvious downside of "the Word version" is its excessive use of vertical and horizontal lines, giving it a rather distinct "prison window cell" appearance. Readers' eyes tend to spend little time taking in the table's contents. Please give the table a much more open and inviting "look" by getting rid of all vertical lines and most horizontal lines. Use the macros of the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/) package to draw the few remaining lines. Your readers will reward your effort by actually *wanting* to take in the table's contents.
- Replace the instances of `/`  ("forward slash") with `\slash`, to avoid needless spaces after the `/` characters while allowing lines to break immediately after the character.

The following screenshot shows the first few rows of the resulting table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xltabular,ragged2e,booktabs,calc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional -- Times Roman fonts

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{%
   @{}
   >{\RaggedRight}p{\widthof{Authentification\ }} % row 1
   l
   >{\RaggedRight}X % row 3
   l 
   @{}}

%% headers and footers
\caption{\dots} \\
\toprule
Fonctionnalités & ID & User story & Priorité \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\tablename\ \thetable, suite de la page précédente} \\[1ex]
\toprule
Fonctionnalités & ID & User story & Priorité \\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{r@{}}{\footnotesize (Suite à la page suivante)} \\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% body of table
Authentification 
 & 1.1 &
  En tant qu’administrateur je dois m’authentifier à la page admin pour y accéder &
  élevée \\ %\cline{2-4} 
 & 1.2 &
  En tant qu’employé RH je dois m’authentifier à la page RH et y accéder &
  élevée \\ %\cline{2-4} 
 & 1.3 &
  En tant que client je dois m’authentifier à la partie pro pour y accéder &
  élevée \\ %\cline{2-4} 
 & 1.4 &
  En tant que webmaster je dois m’authentifier à la page de gestion de contenu pour y accéder &
  élevée \\ %\cline{2-4} 
 & 1.5 &
  En tant que client je peux réinitialiser mon mot de passe &
  moyenne \\ \addlinespace
  
Gestion des comptes 
 & 2.1 &
  En tant qu’administrateur je peux ajouter\slash modifier\slash supprimer des comptes des utilisateurs (Employé RH, client) &
  élevée \\ %\cline{2-4} 
 & 2.2 &
  En tant qu’administrateur je peux consulter les détails d’un compte &
  faible \\ %\cline{2-4} 
 & 2.3 &
  En tant que client je dois envoyer une demande d’inscription qui va être vérifiée par l’administrateur &
  élevée \\ %\cline{2-4} 
 & 2.4 &
  En tant qu’administrateur je peux vérifier les demandes d’inscription &
  élevée \\ \addlinespace

Gestion du contenu 
 & 3.1 &
  En tant que webmaster je peux ajouter\slash modifier\slash supprimer des nouveautés, produits ou solutions &
  élevée \\ %\cline{2-4} 
 & 3.2 &
  En tant qu’utilisateur je peux consulter les nouveautés, produits et solutions &
  élevée \\ %\cline{2-4} 
 & 3.3 &
  En tant que client je souhaite recevoir des notifications à propos les nouveautés &
  faible \\ \addlinespace
  
Gestion des offres de stage et d’emploi 
 & 4.1 &
  En tant que employé RH je peux ajouter\slash modifier\slash supprimer des offres d’emploi ou de stages &
  élevée \\ %\cline{2-4} 
 & 4.2 &
  En tant que employé RH je peux consulter les candidatures &
  élevée \\ %\cline{2-4} 
 & 4.3 &
  En tant qu’utilisateur je peux consulter les offres d’emploi\slash stage &
  élevée \\ %\cline{2-4} 
 & 4.4 &
  En tant qu’utilisateur je peux postuler pour un offre d’emploi\slash stage &
  élevée \\ \addlinespace
  
Gestion des tickets de support
 & 5.1 &
  En tant que client je peux remplir un ticket de support &
  élevée \\ %\cline{2-4} 
 & 5.2 &
  En tant que service client je peux consulter les tickets de support &
  élevée \\ %\cline{2-4} 
 & 5.3 &
  En tant que client je peux envoyer une demande de service &
  élevée \\ \addlinespace

Gestion des documents
 & 6.1 &
  En tant que webmaster je dois sélectionner des clients pour partager des documents &
  élevée \\ %\cline{2-4} 
 & 6.2 &
  En tant que client je peux consulter les documents partagés &
  élevée \\ %\cline{2-4} 
 & 6.3 &
  En tant que client je veux être notifié lors de la réception d’un document &
  faible \\ 
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```